# How to list all function names only, one per line

Tags: ksh, function

In ksh93 `typeset -f` lists all functions and its definition.

```
$ f(){ :; }

$ typeset -f
f(){ :; }
```

With the added quirk that functions that have been defined without a trailing newline are listed the same way:

```
$ g(){ :; }; h(){ :; }
$ k(){ :; }

$ typeset -f
f(){ :; }
g(){ :; };h(){ :; }
k(){ :; }
```

Is there a way to list all function names, better if one per line ?

Failing that:
Is there a way to break such definitions into separate lines ?
I mean: Without doing all the shell parsing to find the function end (or start).

I hope to be able to do `typeset -f functionname` for every function defined in the present script running environment.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution in the manual:

```
$ typeset +f
f()
g()
h()
k()
```

> If +f is specified, then a line containing the function name followed by a shell  comment containing the line number and path name of the file where this function was defined, if any, is displayed.